# How do I stop an infinite loop command on a Discord Bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Let's say I made an infinite command for my bot, Would there be any way to stop the loop at any time? I want to be able to stop it from the server, not in the actual code.

Example:

```
    if(msg.content ===  "Just Monika"){
    msg.channel.send('Just Monika')
    }
})
```

Is there any way I can type something in chat, and it stops the command? thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the looped "infinite command"? Lovely DDLC reference.

Comment: The code I put in is the code I used. Unless you mean something else, otherwise I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Making your bot respond to itself infinitely probably isn't a good idea. But just for learning, it's very possible to do what you wish.

You could make a different phrase (let's call it the stop command) set a boolean variable in your code to true. Then, whenever the looping command gets triggered by a user message or by one of its own, it should check if this boolean telling it to stop is true. If it is, it should set it to false and not send that message, else it should just send that message as per usual.

```
// The following should be defined in the outmost scope
let loopPhrase = "Just Monika";
let stopPhrase = "Stop Spamming The API";

let triggerStop = false;

// The following should be a part of the message event
if (msg.content === loopPhrase) {
    if (!triggerStop) msg.channel.send(loopPhrase);
    else triggerStop = false;
} else if (msg.content === stopPhrase) triggerStop = true;
```

Comment: Where would I put this? I'm new to coding, so I get stuck pretty easily.

Comment: Define the variables in the outermost scope of your js file (eg at the top of the file, maybe below the imports, and not in any event calbacks such as the message event). Then for the message-processing code, place it within the message event's callback function.